# On which manifolds does integration of differential forms make sense?

Tags: calculus

The [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_form) says that integration of differential forms is only well-defined on oriented manifolds.

I suspect that, in addition, the manifold needs to be smooth, compact, and have boundary. Is this true?

Comment: What about $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Non-literal quote from [Integration of Differential Forms](http://www.unc.edu/math/Faculty/met/measg.pdf):

Let be $\omega = \sum_{i\in\ I}\alpha_i$ (locally finite sum), with $\text{supp }\alpha_i\subset U_i$ open subset of $M$, $\varphi_i:{\cal O_i}\subset\Bbb R^n\longrightarrow U_i$ a parametrization that induces the chosen orientation. Then, we can define
$$\int_M\alpha_i = \int_{\cal O_i}\varphi_i^*\alpha_i,\qquad
\int_M\omega = \sum_{i\in\ I}\int_M\alpha_i.$$
(finite sum if $\text{supp }\omega$ is compact)

Is this definition independent of the choice of coordinate system? Yes *for orientation-preserving parametrizations*. Taking two of such parametrizations
$$
\varphi:{\cal O}\longrightarrow U,\qquad \psi:\Omega\longrightarrow U
$$
can be checked that
$$\int_{\cal O}\varphi^*\alpha = \int_\Omega\psi^*\alpha.$$
(application of the theorem of change of variable in $\Bbb R^n$)

Without the orientation-preserving condition, a sign can change.

Comment: What is a locally finite sum?

Comment: @étale-cohomology, for all $x\in M$ only a finite number of $\alpha_i(x)$ are $\ne 0$.